# Windows Sandbox does not work after 20H2 update

Tags: windows, sandbox

I just updated Windows 10 Pro to 20H2 and of course, things are broken.

Photoshop settings gone and Windows Sandbox does not work (I used before), etc. The biggest problem is the Windows Sandbox.

I checked in Windows features, and hyper-v, Sandbox was disabled. I re-enabled, restarted but Sandbox still does not work. I cant start, it is missing from start menu and from taskbar (I pinned before).

So, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Photoshop might need reinstallation (I always need to reinstall some products after a major Windows upgrade). Which error are you getting when trying to open the Sandbox?

Comment: @harrymc No errors because I can't even start Sandbox.

Comment: You could rollback to the previous Windows version, verify that it now works, then redo the upgrade via [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).